# How to figure out (using terminal) which version of python pip is installing to (MacOS)

Tags: python, macos, pip

Question in title. How do I figure out (using terminal) which version of python pip is installing to (Ex. Python 2.7 or Python 3.6). I am looking to use Terminal on MacOS.

Comment: Just check pip's version and it should say which Python it's for. But usually pip means Python2 and pip3 means Python3

Comment: Are you trying to get the version of Python or pip?? It's unclear from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Pip --version command to verify the pip version.

```
$ pip --version
```

if you want to know the version of any library installed, try:

```
$ pip list
```

if you want to know the python version, just simply run in the command line:

```
$ python -v
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
pip -V
```

which will tell you the PIP version and the python version. If you'd like to decide which python version to install to:

```
$ pip2.6 install otherpackage
$ pip2.7 install mybarpackage
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily Google-able, but to save you a few seconds:

```
python --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to find out which version of pip is installed:

```
pip list | grep pip
```